# How to tell the difference between linux and mac

Tags: python-3.x, operating-system, cross-platform

I am creating a setup file for a tarball, and I need a way to determine the exact name of the system.

I tried `os.name`, but it returns 'posix' regardless of whether the system is mac or linux.

Is there a way to get a more specific OS name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.platform
'linux2'
>>>
```

On Mac it outputs something like 'darwin'

Comment: On Yosemite it outputs 'darwin'.